# uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!! on Debian armhf IceWeasel

Tags: arm

### My Setup

- [Radxa Rock PRO](http://radxa.com/Rock) ARM Single board computer
- Debian Wheezy server [prebuilt image for Radxa Rock PRO](http://radxa.com/Rock/prebuilt_images) [download image](http://dl.radxa.com/rock_pro/images/debian/nand/radxa_rock_pro_debian_wheezy_150128_nand.zip) + Xfce desktop

From terminal

```
root@radxa:~# uname -a
Linux radxa 3.0.36+ #14 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 28 19:30:20 CST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

- [USB Microsoft Lifecam Cinema](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/lifecam-cinema)

From terminal

```
root@radxa:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:0724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema  <===========
```

I have installed IceWeasel to be able to test WebRTC.

```
root@radxa:~# iceweasel --version
Mozilla Iceweasel 31.3.0
```

### Issue

To test the camera, I have installed `luvcview` which shows the video stream

[image]

... but when I try `cheese`, it does find the webcam, takes a lots of time to start the application but doesn't stream any video (black)

[image]

... on a test WebRTC session http://opentokrtc.com/test, it prompts to share the Lifecam and starts the session but there is no video stream

[image]

It does pass the getMediaStream. The camera lights up when I refresh the page and click on Share MS Lifecam, only there is no video stream. There is no error message on the browser console.

#### How can I troubleshoot this? This looks like a driver issue.

#### lsmod

```
root@radxa:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
mali                  123306  0 
mali_drm                5228  0 
ump                    27056  1 mali
drm                   142519  1 mali_drm
8723au                852247  0 
uvcvideo               58624  0      <============== changes to 1 when in use
joydev                  8253  0 
rtk_btusb              13105  2 
rk30xxnand_ko         166524  0 
fbcon                  35136  71 
bitblit                 3992  1 fbcon
softcursor               924  1 bitblit
font                    7050  1 fbcon
```

#### dmesg

```
root@radxa:~# dmesg | grep uvc
[ 6441.309090] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.309222] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.309347] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.309458] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.309612] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.309795] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.309900] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310020] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310151] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310330] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310463] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310583] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310700] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310817] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.310927] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311033] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311148] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311250] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311355] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311496] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311600] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311713] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311846] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.311977] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.312101] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.312243] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.312377] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.312510] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.312665] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
[ 6441.312807] uvcvideo: uvc_dequeue_buffer is timeout!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have a beginning of explanation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/radxa/UrAVX-AeJ68)

The kernel is too old to support HD webcams